# VBA - MultiSelect in a DropDown

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Requirement Where a bundle of Items needs to be displayed in the Drop-Down List. The Problem for me is, because there are so many Items inside it, I need to Use Combobox over List-Box. The Reason for that is, if I know the name of the item, I can type in the search box of the drop-down and get my Item, Combo-Box allows you to do that. But the List Box doesn't allow the User Input.

Now, Because there are some which names cannot be remembered, I need to use the Scroll bar in the drop-down to pick up the time. This is hectic, to select a single Item. I would like to have the facility of Using a Multi-select in this case.

**So the Requirements are below:**

1) A Drop-Down that allows the user to type in part of the Input(Say Ref for Refreigerator)

2) A Drop-Down that allows the Multi-select.

Obviously, I don't want to have two drop-downs Splitting the data.

I am open to other Suggestions.

Please Share your thoughts.

Comment: You can't. `ComboBox` only ever has a single selected item. Put a search `TextBox` (heck, or use a `ComboBox` to get autocomplete for free!) atop your `ListBox` control and handle control events accordingly; you'll need a button to remove one/all items from the listbox, too.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I Couldn't agree more with what you are saying. I'm Surprised they don't have this facility for some reason. Can you write a sample example with code as an answer. I will go ahead and mark it. I have searched all the web for one complete day. I couldn't find one single thing useful. It will be useful for many if you can write a brief answer :)

Comment: Not really. Your question is too broad, you asked for ideas and I gave you one - *you* implement it. Ask a question when you're stumped on something more specific.

Comment: I will do that anyways. I will get that done and update the answer :)